# Saving and Displaying Cookies in Table

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have searched, saw some similar-ish questions, but none of them helped me with this particular issue.

I'm really new to Javascript and this is a part of a college assignment.

I have a table with dynamically created rows and columns. I have to save and display cookies from this table using buttons. I have it set up on jsfiddle. However, the cookies part of my code (below) does not work and I really cannot figure out why. Do I need to add another function?

**We can only use Javascript. No libraries or plugins.**

```
createCookie=function(name, value, days){
      var date = new Date();
      date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days*24*60*60*1000));
      var expires = "expires="+ date.toGMTString();
      document.cookie = name + "=" + value + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
      expires + ";path=/";              
}

readCookie=function(){
      var table =document.getElementById('grades');
      var rLen = table.rows.length;
      var cLen = table.rows[1].cells.length;
      var Cookiedata = '';
            for(var i=0;i<rLen;i++) {
                for (var j=0; j<table.rows[i].cells.length; j++) {
                Cookiedata += table.rows[i].cells[j].innerHTML + ",";
                }
            }
      Cookiedata = rLen + "," + cLen + "," + Cookiedata.substring(0, Cookiedata.length);
      setCookie("thatCookie", Cookiedata, 5);
}

delCookie = function(name){
      createCookie(name, "", -1);
}
```

Okay, here is the HTML as requested and Thank You. Unfortunately, I can't post the entire assignment because it's due today.If it gets copied in entirety, our marks will be divided by the number of people who copied it. Risking posting the above cuz I'm stuck. :)

```
<table class="tg" id="grades">
  <tr>
    <th class="tg-baqh" onblur ="func()" colspan ="50" ><b>GRADE AVERAGE CALCULATOR </b>
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th class="tg-wpnc" ></th>
    <th class="tg-wpnc" >Student_Name</th>
    <th class="tg-wpnc">Student_Number</th>
    <th contenteditable="true" class="tg-wpnc" id="exam">Exam</th>
    <th class="tg-wpnc">Final_Grade
      <br>
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr id="student" >
    <TD><input type="checkbox" name="chk"/></TD>
    <td contenteditable="true" class="tg-yw4l" onblur ="func()"></td>
    <td contenteditable="true" class="tg-lqy7" onblur ="func()"></td>
    <td id = "exam" contenteditable="true" class="tg-lqy6" onblur ="func()">-</td>
    <td contenteditable ="false" class="total" ></td>
  </tr>

</table>
<p>

</p>
<button href="#" class="calc_button" onClick="func();">Calculate</button>
 <p>

 </p>
<form action="" onblur ="func()">
<input type="button" href="#" class="calc_button" value="Add a Row" onClick="addRow()">
<p></p>
<input type="button" href="#" class="calc_button" value="Delete Selected Row" onClick="delRow()">
<input type="button" href="#" class="calc_button" value="Delete Bottom Row" onClick="delLastRow()">
<p></p>
<input type="button" href="#" class="calc_button" value="Add a Column" onClick="insertColumn()">

<p></p>
<input type="button" href="#" class="calc_button" value="Save Cookie" onClick="createCookie()">
<input type="button" href="#" class="calc_button" value="Display Cookie" onClick="readCookie()">
<input type="button" href="#" class="calc_button" value="Delete Cookie" onClick="eraseCookie()">
</form>
```

Comment: You need to call the functions somewhere.

Comment: I have buttons underneath my table to call them. When I place alerts inside the functions, they work, however, it's not saving the table rows and columns.

Comment: Can you add the relevant HTML too please?

Comment: Posted up the HTML.  :)

Comment: I just posted your answer. BTW, we don't do assignments here :)))

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a cookie name, value and days when you call the method. I know that you have copied the W3School reference which by the way, is very beneficial. However, remember that whenever you want to run a method, you need to submit the method arguments.

```
<input type="button" href="#" class="calc_button" value="Save Cookie" onClick="createCookie('myCookieName', 'myCookieValue', 1)">
<input type="button" href="#" class="calc_button" value="Display Cookie" onClick="readCookie('myCookieName')">
<input type="button" href="#" class="calc_button" value="Delete Cookie" onClick="eraseCookie('myCookieName')">
```

I did update the onclick events. Take a look!

```js
createCookie=function(name, value, days){
      var date = new Date();
      date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days*24*60*60*1000));
      var expires = "expires="+ date.toGMTString();
      document.cookie = name + "=" + value + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
      expires + ";path=/";              
}

readCookie=function(){
      var table =document.getElementById('grades');
      var rLen = table.rows.length;
      var cLen = table.rows[1].cells.length;
      var Cookiedata = '';
            for(var i=0;i<rLen;i++) {
                for (var j=0; j<table.rows[i].cells.length; j++) {
                Cookiedata += table.rows[i].cells[j].innerHTML + ",";
                }
            }
      Cookiedata = rLen + "," + cLen + "," + Cookiedata.substring(0, Cookiedata.length);
      setCookie("thatCookie", Cookiedata, 5);
}

delCookie = function(name){
      createCookie(name, "", -1);
}
```

```html
<table class="tg" id="grades">
  <tr>
    <th class="tg-baqh" onblur ="func()" colspan ="50" ><b>GRADE AVERAGE CALCULATOR </b>
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th class="tg-wpnc" ></th>
    <th class="tg-wpnc" >Student_Name</th>
    <th class="tg-wpnc">Student_Number</th>
    <th contenteditable="true" class="tg-wpnc" id="exam">Exam</th>
    <th class="tg-wpnc">Final_Grade
      <br>
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr id="student" >
    <TD><input type="checkbox" name="chk"/></TD>
    <td contenteditable="true" class="tg-yw4l" onblur ="func()"></td>
    <td contenteditable="true" class="tg-lqy7" onblur ="func()"></td>
    <td id = "exam" contenteditable="true" class="tg-lqy6" onblur ="func()">-</td>
    <td contenteditable ="false" class="total" ></td>
  </tr>

</table>
<p>

</p>
<button href="#" class="calc_button" onClick="func();">Calculate</button>
 <p>

 </p>
<form action="" onblur ="func()">
<input type="button" href="#" class="calc_button" value="Add a Row" onClick="addRow()">
<p></p>
<input type="button" href="#" class="calc_button" value="Delete Selected Row" onClick="delRow()">
<input type="button" href="#" class="calc_button" value="Delete Bottom Row" onClick="delLastRow()">
<p></p>
<input type="button" href="#" class="calc_button" value="Add a Column" onClick="insertColumn()">

<p></p>
<input type="button" href="#" class="calc_button" value="Save Cookie" onClick="createCookie('myCookieName', 'myCookieValue', 1)">
<input type="button" href="#" class="calc_button" value="Display Cookie" onClick="readCookie('myCookieName')">
<input type="button" href="#" class="calc_button" value="Delete Cookie" onClick="eraseCookie('myCookieName')">
</form>
```

P.S: The method cannot work here because of the browser security settings. Run it at your HTML debugger.

Comment: Thanks AHBagheri, yes, we were told to use W3schools to learn javascript. It's not actually taught in class. They generally teach us through Java. Sorry new to stackoverflow and posted my thanks in the wrong place. As for not helping with assignments, I'm a postgrad student doing programming for the first time, so I know it's in my best interest to try my hardest to get it right by myself before asking for help,  ;) and this is only part of a larger assignment that I had two weeks to complete.

I still wasn't able to get it working. 

Thanks for the help. :)

Comment: Yes, I changed those. Still didn't work. I've already submitted the assignment since I had to have it in, but still interested in finding out what on earth I did wrong.